# Getting started with AR on the iPhone: How to position things?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, augmented-reality

Just starting to play with Augmented Reality on the iPhone ... and I have some questions:

1. How do you position elements on the screen?  I assume that it is based on a given longitude, latitude and altitude (but I could be wrong)???
2. Any solid resources, tutorials, etc... dedicated to building AR type apps for iOS?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jonathansaggau.com/blog/2010/10/iphone_ipad_devcon_sample_code.html

This is a talk with sample code. If you understand atan, sin, cos, you are halfway there.